# Formulas for the area of a rectangle, other than $l \times w$.

Tags: geometry

> So you're asked to show two formulas for the area of a rectangle. They can't include the classic $A=l \times w$

This is all I have come up with $$A=\int_0^{l}wdx$$ It doesn't matter how complex they are. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: use double integral: 1 for the length and other for the height

Comment: $\frac12 d^2 \sin\theta$, where $d$ is the length of the diagonal, and $\theta$ is the angle between the two diagonals. (For a general quadrilateral, replace $d^2$ with $d_1 d_2$.)

Comment: So can I use $\int_0^{l}\int_0^{w}1dydx$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the perimeter of the rectangle and $C$ the area of the circle which circumscribes the rectangle. Then
$$
A=\frac{p^2}{8} - \frac{2C }{\pi}.
$$